# cant successfully nest div within another div

Tags: html, css

I get this will have been answered elsewhere but Im finding too much noise in the css to understand what is going on.  Tutorials have me going in circles - simple question I think; how in the code below do I get the div class='mod' to be contained inside of the div class='body' ? When I try to do this the white div sits outside of and below its intended parent. The container should fill screen dimensions, the sidebar sit to the left of screen at fixed width x screen height, and the mod box inside the body div.

```
<style>
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:blue;

}

.sidebar {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}

.mod { 
    height:100px; 
    width:100px; 
    background:white; 
    border:1px solid;

}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="mod"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/carlv/r2mo03hh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mod` div IS inside of the `body` div, but `body` also is wrapped around `mod` so that you can't "see" it. However, the `body` element is not positioned next to the side-bar. I recommend you learn how to use your browser's inspection tool to inspect where your elements actually are, their size and so on *(there are plenty resources on the internet so I won't teach you how here).*

The default behavior for the div element is to place underneath one another, since the `sidebar` is filling the `container`, body "overflows" and looks to be displayed underneath `container`.

If you want divs to appear in line you have to add the css code `display: inline-block` to the sibling divs that are to be displayed next to one another *(in this case `sidebar` and `body`)*. This will place them next to one another as blocks.

[As you can see in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwtujrd0/1/), the `mod` div is now next to the sidebar. If you inspect the `body` div you will find that body is now the same length as the sidebar and `mod` gets placed in the bottom left of body.

[If you have a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yLjtufg/) where I've added the code `float: left;` to `body` and it's sibling `sidebar` you will now see that `body` instead of sizing to the parent (which is wrapping sidebar) it's now only sizing to its content, `mod`.

What float does is telling the sibling divs that they are supposed to stay next to the element to the left of it, which in this case breaks the default placement under the sibling div and places it next to it instead.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response. It answered question but unfortunately I couldnt push on to extend these concepts. Looks like back to table, but you answered the question thoroughly and with examples.

Comment: CSS is a mess to learn. I've been dealing with it for 10+ years and I learn new ways to handle them all the time. The best tip I can give you is to read through [an entire reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) and experiment your heart away. Don't reference w3schools until you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below style. You are missing "float:left".

```
<style>
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:blue;

}

.sidebar {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

.body{
    float:left;
}

.mod { 
    height:100px; 
    width:100px; 
    background:white; 
    border:1px solid;

}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to put two containers side by side, you need to float them. By default they will always stack one on top of the other.

I've changed a code a bit, because height:100% won't give you the result you want because of lack of content:

```
<style>
   .container {
    background-color:blue;
    min-height:150px;
}
.sidebar {
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    background:red;
    float:left;}

.body{float:left;}
.mod { 
    height:100px; 
    width:100px; 
    background:white; 
    border:1px solid;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar">&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="mod"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for assistance - I wasnt able to progress this further so using a table in page to control layout instead.

Answer (score 0):

DIV elements are by default displayed as blocks. So even though you have assigned a width to `.sidebar` div element, it spreads to the rest of the screen. Either you should use `float:left` on both `.sidebar` and `.body` classes

```
   .body
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .sidebar {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      background: red;
      float: left;
    }
```

or should add `display:inline-block` for both of them.

```
.body
{
   display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Both of these solutions will wrap the the .body element inside it's parent element in two different ways. You need to pick the most appropriate style for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

CSS

.container
{ position:relative; }

.sidebar
{ position:absolute;}

.mod 
{left:300px;
position:absolute;}

Answer (score 0):

#### To Keep the two div side by side, add the below css property to the parent div#

```
.container{
display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - however that adds flex to my lack of understanding of layout so will steer clear of this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide width to .body class and because you are giving a 100% of height to element and not using float, It's going down.
I have made some minor changes to your fiddle code paste this css there:

```
<style>
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    background:blue;
}

.sidebar {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    float: left;
}
.body{
    width:300px;
    float: left;
}

.mod { height:100px; width:100px; background:white; border:1px solid;}
</style>
```